# selenium - detect colors

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

is there a way to detect colors by Selenium (priority to phpunit selenium).

I have banners in the site and some of them doesn't reloaded, it strange I have their element but all I see on the screen is only a white color. I want use selenium to check when find if it happens again. if there are banner with a white color.

is there a chance it possible?

Comment: You can get the CSS property of any web element. By there you can get the color of the web element(here banner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the screenshot and try the following.

```
<?php 
    $image = new Imagick('testimage.jpg'); 
    $x = 1;  
    $y = 1; 
    $pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y); 
?>
```

You can also check this Library[php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ncurses.php) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done using **java.awt.Robot** | I haven't tried any for PHP

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.getPixelColor(923, 87);
```